# In Flutter, How can I detect the change if the headset is suddenly plugged

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to find the method about detecting headset in Flutter.
I want to hide AlertDialog when the headset is connected.
I know that I can detect connection by using 'Initstate()'.
But, I think It's not appropriate using Initstate.
Because If user see the Alertdialog, they can plug their headset anytime and then allowed to close the Alertdialog.
I use GetX. Is there any method for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `headset_connection_event`package: https://pub.dev/packages/headset_connection_event

It work both with physical headset plug and with blutooth headset.

Implementation example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:headset_connection_event/headset_event.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _headsetPlugin = HeadsetEvent();
  HeadsetState? _headsetState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// if headset is plugged
    _headsetPlugin.getCurrentState.then((_val) {
      setState(() {
        _headsetState = _val;
      });
    });

    /// Detect the moment headset is plugged or unplugged
    _headsetPlugin.setListener((_val) {
      setState(() {
        _headsetState = _val;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Headset Event Plugin'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.headset,
                  color: this._headsetState == HeadsetState.CONNECT ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                ),
                Text('State : $_headsetState\n'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```